# My Cocoapods framework methods are not available by import in another app

Tags: swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm new in frameworks creating, so I have some troubles and need your help :)
I have published [my first Cocoapods framework](https://github.com/krotoff/KrotoffSwiftExtensions).
I installed it in another project and try to use anything public from my public extensions, but it has no visible properties or methods.
I just tried many times to set again source_files property in podspec, but with my knowledge it's useless.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the Mac. And more specifically in the trunk on Mac.
I made this pod on this Mac and then I tried to use it here.

So the solution is:

```
pod repo remove trunk
```

And then install, update - do anything you want. It will work.

Thanks to @MilanPanchal for his time and support!

Answer (score 1):

I've installed your framework using CocoaPods:

```
pod 'KrotoffSwiftExtensions'
```

Then I've access `setPlaceholder` method from `UITextField` extension:

```
import KrotoffSwiftExtensions

txtField.setPlaceholder(text: "Enter Email", color: UIColor.brown)
```

Please let us know If you are still facing any issue:

Comment: Yes, the issue is still here. I can't use anything from my framework.

Comment: I used these commands:

rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/"
pod update

Comment: Try to import KrotoffSwiftExtensions and use CoordinatableViewController, but here is an error: "Use of undeclared type 'CoordinatableViewController'"

Comment: I'm able to use CoordinatableViewController class also. After installing your framework through CocoaPods, are you opening your project using *.xcworkspace file?

Comment: Yes, exactly this way, as usual :)

Comment: Please share your Xcode folder structure with Pods Folder

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15ynsB0YLdjKUfBDrYlEJqvNy__tXmKby/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @AndrewKrotov Used your Zip file and able to use functions from your Podfile. Not sure what's the issue is. One thing I notice is your cocoa pod version is 1.10.0.beta.2 (You can see Podfile.lock) and I'm on version 1.9.3.

Comment: @AndrewKrotov Specify platform in Podfile too (https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform)

Comment: Maybe it's a curse :D I just removed all pod data from my mac, installed Cocoapods 1.9.3, clarified the platform, installed pods again, and...nothing.

Comment: Okay. I'll just try to open an issue on the official cocoapods github. Maybe they know smth. Thank you very much for your attention and tries to help me, Milan :)

Comment: Aaaand it was a bad idea: they just return me back to stackoverflow to wait an answer